# GetCurrent Month from yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: java, mysql

This is code for get current date information is getting from database. It is working successfully.

```
public class RetailerWs {
  public int data(){
    int count=0;

    //count++;

    try{
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      Connection con = DriverManager
         .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pro","root","");

      PreparedStatement statement =  con
         .prepareStatement("select * from orders where status='Q' AND date=CURDATE()");
      ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();

      while(result.next()) {
        // Do something with the row returned.
        count++; //if the first col is a count.
      }     
    }
    catch (Exception exc) {
      System.out.println(exc.getMessage());
    }


    return count;
  }
}
```

my doubt is **how is get current month details from database.**..how to do that...please help me.

dis is my database:

[image]

Here i wish to need output is if i run the above application means it is displayed the count value.if i wish to need output is the current month details.for eg:i get the current date information means the check the query and display count value is 2..it is worked successfully.here i wrote the query is

```
select * from orders where status='Q' AND date=CURDATE()".
```

it is successfully worked.same thing how is write the query for status=Q for current month...so now i wish to display the output is 2.but i can't unable to do dis.so please help me.how is to do.how can i change my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try function `MONTH()` of mysql
 [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month)

Comment: dis link unable to open for me.its displayed problem loading error.please send me that code

Comment: @krishnaveni its working fine, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month

Comment: i have use this query:select * from xcart_orders where status='Q' AND MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURDATE()) AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURDATE())..it is successful

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
select month(CURDATE())
```

or

```
select date_format(now(),'%M')as Month_name
```

to get the month number

```
select date_format('2012-07-26','%m')as Month_number
```

**Answer to your updated question:**

```
select count(*) from orders where status='Q' AND date=CURDATE()"
```

Just add count(*) in your query will give you result '2'

Comment: @krishnaveni: How do you need your out put ?

Comment: in my database have one field  yyyy-mm-dd format.i get the information from dis format to get only month value.

Comment: @krishnaveni: select date_format('2012-07-26','%M')as Month_name

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14789/discussion-between-krishnaveni-and-joe-g-joseph)

Comment: i have use this query:select * from xcart_orders where status='Q' AND MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURDATE()) AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURDATE())..it is successful